# Regex to not match tab, carriage return and square brackets

Tags: regex

I need a regex to not match tab, carriage return and square brackets. (C#)

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
[^\][\t\r]
```

- `[]` - char class
- `^` - negation of char class.
- `\]` - escape ] as ] is a meta char
  inside a char class
- `[` - need not escape `[` as inside `[]`
  its not a meta char
- `\t` - tab
- `\r` - return carriage

Comment: I think you are missing `\n` in symbol class

Comment: OP doesn't mention new-lines.

Answer (score 1):

should be:

```
[^\t\r\[\]]
```

or for the whole string:

```
^[^\t\r\[\]]*$
```

Comment: You need not escape [ inside a char class.

Comment: Well, true. But in this case it might be less confusing.

Comment: Agreed: it's ugly either way, but it's a little less confusing with the backslash.  Besides, in some flavors you *do* have to escape the `[`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[\w]+
```

Will match any word character (alphanumeric & underscore).

Comment: And what about all the other characters that are not tabs, carriage-returns or square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my ($s) = @ARGV;

if ( $s =~ /^[^\r\t\[\]]*\z/ ) {
    print "$s contains no carriage returns, tabs or square brackets\n";
}
```